маршрутизация в ubuntu для vpn клиента
Я новичок в сетевом программировании и пытаюсь создать свой VPN. Для этого я использую следующий код:
import pytun as pt
tun = pt.TunTapDevice(name='mytun')
tun.addr = '127.0.0.1'
tun.dstaddr = '127.0.0.2'
tun.mtu = 1500
tun.up()

while True:
    data = tun.read(tun.mtu)

По задумке, мой VPN-клиент должен создать tun интерфейс (с названием mytun), который будут прослушивать остальные программы. После того как байты считываются моим виртуальным интерфейсом, они отправляются в программу, которая через сокеты отправляет их серверу.
Мне нужно маршрутизировать все приложения на моём ПК так, чтобы они прослушивали мой виртуальный сетевой интерфейс «mytun», но при этом я мог отправлять пакеты через свою реальную сетевую карту. Я пытался использовать команду ip route add 192.168.1.31 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev mytun , но, видимо, делал это неправильно.

tun0, mytun - определитесь.

да и  сокет ещё не доделан. рано вам ещё за весь трафик

@eri скрипт с сокетами есть, я хочу сначала попробывать перенаправить трафик в ubuntu
